error while starting mutt in tmux
when i'm launching mutt in terminal it works well and all the colors are loaded correctly but when i switch to tmux it gives me this error:
Error in /Users/amir/.mutt/muttrc, line 35: 231: color not supported by term
Error in /Users/amir/.mutt/muttrc, line 36: 231: color not supported by term
Error in /Users/amir/.mutt/muttrc, line 37: 210: color not supported by term
Error in /Users/amir/.mutt/muttrc, line 41: 84: color not supported by term
Error in /Users/amir/.mutt/muttrc, line 42: 141: color not supported by term
Error in /Users/amir/.mutt/muttrc, line 43: 231: color not supported by term
Error in /Users/amir/.mutt/muttrc, line 44: 141: color not supported by term
Error in /Users/amir/.mutt/muttrc, line 47: 210: color not supported by term
Error in /Users/amir/.mutt/muttrc, line 48: 84: color not supported by term
Error in /Users/amir/.mutt/muttrc, line 49: 117: color not supported by term
Error in /Users/amir/.mutt/muttrc, line 50: 212: color not supported by term
Error in /Users/amir/.mutt/muttrc, line 51: 215: color not supported by term
Error in /Users/amir/.mutt/muttrc, line 52: 141: color not supported by term
Error in /Users/amir/.mutt/muttrc, line 55: 117: color not supported by term
Error in /Users/amir/.mutt/muttrc, line 56: 231: color not supported by term
Error in /Users/amir/.mutt/muttrc, line 59: 228: color not supported by term
Error in /Users/amir/.mutt/muttrc, line 60: 231: color not supported by term
Error in /Users/amir/.mutt/muttrc, line 61: 228: color not supported by term
Error in /Users/amir/.mutt/muttrc, line 62: 231: color not supported by term
Error in /Users/amir/.mutt/muttrc, line 63: 231: color not supported by term
Error in /Users/amir/.mutt/muttrc, line 64: 231: color not supported by term
Error in /Users/amir/.mutt/muttrc, line 65: 61: color not supported by term
Error in /Users/amir/.mutt/muttrc, line 66: 117: color not supported by term
Error in /Users/amir/.mutt/muttrc, line 67: 84: color not supported by term
Error in /Users/amir/.mutt/muttrc, line 68: 215: color not supported by term
Error in /Users/amir/.mutt/muttrc, line 69: 212: color not supported by term
Error in /Users/amir/.mutt/muttrc, line 70: 212: color not supported by term
source: errors in /Users/amir/.mutt/muttrc
Press any key to continue...

i couldn't find any solution, might be problem with muttrc?
here's my muttrc config:
###############################################################################
# Dracula Theme for Mutt: https://draculatheme.com/
#
# @author Paul Townsend <paul@caprica.org>

# general ------------ foreground ---- background -----------------------------
color error     color231    color212
color indicator     color231    color241
color markers       color210    default
color message       default     default
color normal        default     default
color prompt        default         default
color search        color84     default
color status        color141    color236
color tilde     color231    default
color tree      color141    default

# message index ------ foreground ---- background -----------------------------
color index     color210    default     ~D # deleted messages
color index     color84     default     ~F # flagged messages
color index     color117    default     ~N # new messages
color index     color212    default     ~Q # messages which have been replied to
color index     color215    default     ~T # tagged messages
color index     color141    default     ~v # messages part of a collapsed thread

# message headers ---- foreground ---- background -----------------------------
color hdrdefault    color117    default
color header        color231    default     ^Subject:.*

# message body ------- foreground ---- background -----------------------------
color attachment    color228    default
color body      color231    default     [\-\.+_a-zA-Z0-9]+@[\-\.a-zA-Z0-9]+               # email addresses
color body      color228    default     (https?|ftp)://[\-\.,/%~_:?&=\#a-zA-Z0-9]+        # URLs
color body      color231    default     (^|[[:space:]])\\*[^[:space:]]+\\*([[:space:]]|$) # *bold* text
color body      color231    default     (^|[[:space:]])_[^[:space:]]+_([[:space:]]|$)     # _underlined_ text
color body      color231    default     (^|[[:space:]])/[^[:space:]]+/([[:space:]]|$)     # /italic/ text
color quoted        color61     default
color quoted1       color117    default
color quoted2       color84     default
color quoted3       color215    default
color quoted4       color212    default
color signature     color212    default



Please [edit] the question to include the contents of .muttrc.

Use
set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"

in your tmux.conf to make it advertise 256-color capability.

Thanks it fixed my problem
